# SATA to mmc with custom FW

Tags: microcontroller, usb, sata, emmc, mmc

I want to minimize the price of the device (board) with the next functionality: it connects to M2 and supports SATA to internal emmc memory (access to memory through functional block).

That functional block could be as any controller or something -- should be programmable.

So, my question is: what platform can you advise to use as a functional block?

For me, it seems not bad to use TI AM1808.

Also, there is ideas to use some usb-sata bridge, to have something like (with no success for sata-to-usb adapter)

```
sata host| ] --> [ |sata to usb| --> | (usb) mcu (emmc) | --> emmc ]
   host-side     board-side
```

Comment: There's to my knowledge no cheap solutions for a SATA link to become USB host (that makes no sense, functionally), so I think this is where your idea fails. But you don't seem to be clear about what you actually need: most m.2 slots offer USB from the host, so you don't need that at all. However, if you really want sata-to-emmc, well a) cost optimizing would probably be finding the Chinese supplier that happens to have such (I'm sure they exist, I used sata-to-sdcard bridges privately) chips, b) next best thing would be using a cheap FPGA that plays the role of a SATA device and talks to eMMC.

Comment: a) can you help what chip pn do you use for your bridge? or specify how flexible it could be support? is that just arm with vendor sdk? Because, for my googling I found many suitable solutions, but as I undrestood fw provided as it is.

Comment: ee j a cursory amazon search yields https://www.amazon.de/Card-Secure-Digital-Adapter-konform/dp/B018GTFQR8, which seems to use [FC1307A](http://www.kwanghua.cn/cn/DowsnLoad.aspx?srcfile=/GSUpLoadFiles/20121227/2012122715531404.pdf) .

Comment: yes-yes, I saw it many times, but is that really possible to make custom fw for such controller? I've found only several attempts to reverse with not a big success actually.

Comment: The thing is, you under-define what your firmware needs to do. I'd probably just put a processor between your mmc interface and the card. You can also just hot-glue an 8051 to the top of such a device if you don't actually need to define what the firmware you add does.

Comment: Thanks, mmmm! This is new idea for me and I will research in that direction. Like mmc-mmc bridge with func block. If you will have any other suggestion, feel free to write, it definitely help a lot.